# JavaScript, create objects inside array with 2 objects only

Tags: javascript

I want to create an array with 2 objects, and each of those object will have objects inside:

This is the expected result:

```
[ 
   { 
      "myLayersArray":{ 
         "0":{ 
            "type":"myLayers",
            "filetype":"kml",
            "layerId":"kml-a00c9798-e2a5-4098-9814-0356527fc220",
            "id":1749
         }
      }
   },
   { 
      "figuresArray":{ 
         "0":{ 
            "type":"figure",
            "layerId":"polygon-6e0df465-af64-437e-a451-530e3553aae5",
            "id":1026
         },
         "1":{ 
            "type":"figure",
            "layerId":"polygon-bc371cbf-8e6d-4a26-bdbd-ad1ca3d4700c",
            "id":1031
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Currently, I have 2 `foreachs` like this:

```
let data = []
const layer = {}
myLayers.layers.forEach( (a,i) => {
  visibleLayers.layers.forEach( (b,j) => {
    if (a.layerId === b.id) {
      layer.type = 'myLayers'
      layer.filetype = a.fileType ? a.fileType : "other"
      layer.layerId = b.id
      layer.id = a.id
      data.push({'myLayers': layer})
    }
  })
})

const element = {}
figures.items.forEach( (a,i) => {
  visibleLayers.layers.forEach( (b,j) => {
    if (a.layerId === b.id) {
      element.type = 'figure'
      element.layerId = b.id
      element.id = a.id
      data.push({'figures': element})
    }
  })
})

console.log('objResult', data)

But I got this:
```

[image]

What should I change? I want to have just 1 figure object with all their objects inside

EDIT:

This is the data:

```
myLayers.items[ 
   { 
      "id":1750,
      "user_id":1020,
      "filename":"Curico_Test_Share7.kmz",
      "fullname":"1572898499.kmz",
      "full_path":"https://georesearch-mastergeo.s3.amazonaws.com/1572898499.kmz",
      "file_extension":"kmz",
      "file_size":"6276",
      "mime_type":"application/zip",
      "shared":false,
      "created_at":"2019-11-04 20:14:59",
      "updated_at":"2019-11-04 20:14:59",
      "alias":"CURICO_TEST_SHARE7.KMZ",
      "information":null,
      "profile_id":1,
      "layerId":"kmz-0eeb9a1d-5442-477e-bca3-b7fadd6900d2",
      "fileType":"kmz"
   },
   { 
      "id":1749,
      "user_id":1020,
      "filename":"cuadrado poligono.kml",
      "fullname":"1572898478.kml",
      "full_path":"https://georesearch-mastergeo.s3.amazonaws.com/1572898478.kml",
      "file_extension":"kml",
      "file_size":"376",
      "mime_type":"text/xml",
      "shared":false,
      "created_at":"2019-11-04 20:14:38",
      "updated_at":"2019-11-04 20:14:38",
      "alias":"CUADRADO POLIGONO.KML",
      "information":null,
      "profile_id":1,
      "layerId":"kml-f4cb4869-e448-4574-b8d0-e0538b829388",
      "fileType":"kml",
      "isActived":true
   },
   { 
      "id":1751,
      "user_id":1020,
      "filename":"test kmz.kml",
      "fullname":"1572898515.kml",
      "full_path":"https://georesearch-mastergeo.s3.amazonaws.com/1572898515.kml",
      "file_extension":"kml",
      "file_size":"420",
      "mime_type":"text/xml",
      "shared":false,
      "created_at":"2019-11-04 20:15:15",
      "updated_at":"2019-11-04 20:15:15",
      "alias":"TEST KMZ.KML",
      "information":null,
      "profile_id":1,
      "layerId":"kml-1324a441-2767-4ad9-835b-70bf4f32e730",
      "fileType":"kml"
   }
]

visibleLayers.layers[ 
   { 
      "id":"polygon-c33a2008-edb2-415d-99e9-fab264ec1596",
      "name":"test dibujo"
   },
   { 
      "id":"polygon-a373e86b-0068-444b-8a13-4743a022dfb8",
      "name":"asdas"
   },
   { 
      "id":"kml-f4cb4869-e448-4574-b8d0-e0538b829388",
      "name":"CUADRADO POLIGONO.KML"
   }
]
```

Comment: please add valid data and what you like to get from it (as text).

Comment: What are the `myLayers.items` and `figures.items` arrays?

Comment: Editing with the console of those vars, please wait

Comment: What you want to create is not clear enough. "An array with two objects" doesn't seem sufficient info.

Comment: Edited again, sorry, check the expected data in the first lines of my question

Comment: you data does not match that wanted new structure. please add an example which data match.

Comment: I finally got it, I'll put my code and screenshots of data as an answer, but the way that I'm doing it is awful. The answer will help to help me

Comment: please do us a favor, remove all images and add the (source) data, you have as text and the wanted result as well as text to the question.

Comment: Done. The expected result (I had to `stringify` the output from my answer) and the source data, in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing the wrong object into the array.
Here is how you can edit the code to get the desired result.

```
let data = {}; //changed array to object
const layer = {}

data.myLayers = []; //added myLayers property to data
data.figures = []; //added figures property to data
myLayers.items.forEach( (a,i) => {
  visibleLayers.layers.forEach( (b,j) => {
    if (a.layerId === b.id) {
      layer.type = 'myLayers'
      layer.filetype = a.fileType ? a.fileType : "other"
      layer.layerId = b.id
      layer.id = a.id
      data.myLayers.push(layer); //changed line
    }
  })
})

const element = {}
figures.items.forEach( (a,i) => {
  visibleLayers.layers.forEach( (b,j) => {
    if (a.layerId === b.id) {
      element.type = 'figure'
      element.layerId = b.id
      element.id = a.id
      data.figures.push(element); //changed line
    }
  })
})

console.log('objResult', data)
//if you want to get the JSON string
var json = JSON.stringify(data)
console.log('jsonResult', json)
```

Below is a simplified code snippet to show the result.

```js
let data = {}

data.myLayers = []
data.figures = [];

data.myLayers.push( {'type':'Layer', 'id':'101'} );
data.myLayers.push( {'type':'Layer', 'id':'102'} );

data.figures.push( {'type' : 'Figure', 'id' : 201} );
data.figures.push( {'type' : 'Figure', 'id' : 202} );

console.log('objResult', data);
console.log('jsonResult', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a problem with this. I'm pushing the same element  twice on each foreachs. I got this with your implementation https://i.imgur.com/7Vrl1nB.png. EDIT: Fixed, I moved the `const layer = {}` and `const element = {}` inside the foreach, now I have new elements on each iteration. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Had a go at getting the output as close to what you wanted as possible, while also trying to fix your use of an `object` as an `array` - also makes it a little cleaner.

To save you scrolling, the output looks like

```
[
  myLayersArray: [{
    type: 'myLayers',
    fileType: 'kml',
    layerId: 'kml-f4cb4869-e448-4574-b8d0-e0538b829388',
    id: 1749
  }],
  myFiguresArray: [{
    type: 'figures',
    layerId: 'polygon-bc371cbf-8e6d-4a26-bdbd-ad1ca3d4700c',
    id: 1031
  }, {
    type: 'figures',
    layerId: 'polygon-6e0df465-af64-437e-a451-530e3553aae5',
    id: 1026
  }]
]
```

```js
let myLayers = {
  items: [{ 
      "id":1750,
      "user_id":1020,
      "filename":"Curico_Test_Share7.kmz",
      "fullname":"1572898499.kmz",
      "full_path":"https://georesearch-mastergeo.s3.amazonaws.com/1572898499.kmz",
      "file_extension":"kmz",
      "file_size":"6276",
      "mime_type":"application/zip",
      "shared":false,
      "created_at":"2019-11-04 20:14:59",
      "updated_at":"2019-11-04 20:14:59",
      "alias":"CURICO_TEST_SHARE7.KMZ",
      "information":null,
      "profile_id":1,
      "layerId":"kmz-0eeb9a1d-5442-477e-bca3-b7fadd6900d2",
      "fileType":"kmz"
   }, { 
      "id":1749,
      "user_id":1020,
      "filename":"cuadrado poligono.kml",
      "fullname":"1572898478.kml",
      "full_path":"https://georesearch-mastergeo.s3.amazonaws.com/1572898478.kml",
      "file_extension":"kml",
      "file_size":"376",
      "mime_type":"text/xml",
      "shared":false,
      "created_at":"2019-11-04 20:14:38",
      "updated_at":"2019-11-04 20:14:38",
      "alias":"CUADRADO POLIGONO.KML",
      "information":null,
      "profile_id":1,
      "layerId":"kml-f4cb4869-e448-4574-b8d0-e0538b829388",
      "fileType":"kml",
      "isActived":true
   }, { 
      "id":1751,
      "user_id":1020,
      "filename":"test kmz.kml",
      "fullname":"1572898515.kml",
      "full_path":"https://georesearch-mastergeo.s3.amazonaws.com/1572898515.kml",
      "file_extension":"kml",
      "file_size":"420",
      "mime_type":"text/xml",
      "shared":false,
      "created_at":"2019-11-04 20:15:15",
      "updated_at":"2019-11-04 20:15:15",
      "alias":"TEST KMZ.KML",
      "information":null,
      "profile_id":1,
      "layerId":"kml-1324a441-2767-4ad9-835b-70bf4f32e730",
      "fileType":"kml"
   }]
};

let figures = {
  items: [{ 
      "id":1026,
      "user_id":1020,
      "filename":"Curico_Test_Share7.kmz",
      "fullname":"1572898499.kmz",
      "full_path":"https://georesearch-mastergeo.s3.amazonaws.com/1572898499.kmz",
      "file_extension":"kmz",
      "file_size":"6276",
      "mime_type":"application/zip",
      "shared":false,
      "created_at":"2019-11-04 20:14:59",
      "updated_at":"2019-11-04 20:14:59",
      "alias":"CURICO_TEST_SHARE7.KMZ",
      "information":null,
      "profile_id":1,
      "layerId":"polygon-6e0df465-af64-437e-a451-530e3553aae5",
      "fileType":"kmz"
   }, { 
      "id":1031,
      "user_id":1020,
      "filename":"cuadrado poligono.kml",
      "fullname":"1572898478.kml",
      "full_path":"https://georesearch-mastergeo.s3.amazonaws.com/1572898478.kml",
      "file_extension":"kml",
      "file_size":"376",
      "mime_type":"text/xml",
      "shared":false,
      "created_at":"2019-11-04 20:14:38",
      "updated_at":"2019-11-04 20:14:38",
      "alias":"CUADRADO POLIGONO.KML",
      "information":null,
      "profile_id":1,
      "layerId":"polygon-bc371cbf-8e6d-4a26-bdbd-ad1ca3d4700c",
      "fileType":"kml",
      "isActived":true
   }, { 
      "id":1751,
      "user_id":1020,
      "filename":"test kmz.kml",
      "fullname":"1572898515.kml",
      "full_path":"https://georesearch-mastergeo.s3.amazonaws.com/1572898515.kml",
      "file_extension":"kml",
      "file_size":"420",
      "mime_type":"text/xml",
      "shared":false,
      "created_at":"2019-11-04 20:15:15",
      "updated_at":"2019-11-04 20:15:15",
      "alias":"TEST KMZ.KML",
      "information":null,
      "profile_id":1,
      "layerId":"polygon-6e0df465-af64-437e-a451-530e3553bae5",
      "fileType":"kml"
   }]
};

let visibleLayers = {
  layers : [{ 
      "id":"polygon-bc371cbf-8e6d-4a26-bdbd-ad1ca3d4700c",
      "name":"test dibujo"
   }, { 
      "id":"polygon-6e0df465-af64-437e-a451-530e3553aae5",
      "name":"asdas"
   }, { 
      "id":"kml-f4cb4869-e448-4574-b8d0-e0538b829388",
      "name":"CUADRADO POLIGONO.KML"
   }]
};


let data = [];

let myLayersArray = [];
let myFiguresArray = [];

visibleLayers.layers.forEach((visibleLayer) => {
  myLayers.items.forEach((myLayer) => {
    if (visibleLayer.id === myLayer.layerId) {
      myLayersArray.push({
        'type': 'myLayers',
        'fileType': myLayer.fileType ? myLayer.fileType : 'other',
        'layerId': visibleLayer.id,
        'id': myLayer.id
      });
    }
  }),
  figures.items.forEach((myFigure) => {
    if (visibleLayer.id === myFigure.layerId) {
      myFiguresArray.push({
        'type': 'figures',
        'layerId': visibleLayer.id,
        'id': myFigure.id
      });
    }
  })
})

data['myLayersArray'] = myLayersArray;
data['myFiguresArray'] = myFiguresArray;

// Keeps the names
console.log(data.myLayersArray);
console.log(data.myFiguresArray);

// Can still access by index
console.log(data.myFiguresArray[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = []
let myLayersArray = {}
let figuresArray = {}
let count = 0
myLayers.items.forEach( (a,i) => {
  visibleLayers.layers.forEach( (b,j) => {
    if (a.layerId === b.id) {
      let layer = {}
      layer.type = 'myLayers'
      layer.filetype = a.fileType ? a.fileType : "other"
      layer.layerId = b.id
      layer.id = a.id
      myLayersArray[count] = layer
      count++
    }
  })
})

count = 0
figures.items.forEach( (a,i) => {
  visibleLayers.layers.forEach( (b,j) => {
    if (a.layerId === b.id) {
      let element = {}
      element.type = 'figure'
      element.layerId = b.id
      element.id = a.id
      figuresArray[count] = element
      count++
    }
  })
})
data.push({'myLayersArray': myLayersArray})
data.push({'figuresArray': figuresArray})

console.log('objResult', JSON.stringify(data))
```

So I got this (this is what I wanted):

```
[ 
   { 
      "myLayersArray":{ 
         "0":{ 
            "type":"myLayers",
            "filetype":"kml",
            "layerId":"kml-a00c9798-e2a5-4098-9814-0356527fc220",
            "id":1749
         }
      }
   },
   { 
      "figuresArray":{ 
         "0":{ 
            "type":"figure",
            "layerId":"polygon-6e0df465-af64-437e-a451-530e3553aae5",
            "id":1026
         },
         "1":{ 
            "type":"figure",
            "layerId":"polygon-bc371cbf-8e6d-4a26-bdbd-ad1ca3d4700c",
            "id":1031
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Now I want to get rid off that `count++` and use of so many `let`